# Searching for element in array in aurelia view

Tags: binding, aurelia

I am using `if.bind` to conditionally display elements in a view. In my current case, I have something similar to

```
<template>  
  <h2 if.bind="car.model === 'Ferrari' || car.model === 'Ford` || car.model === 'Renault'">
     ${ car.price}
  </h2>
</template>
```

I am looking to shorten the `if.bind` to something like `if.bind="car.model in allModels` in order to avoid having many `||`

(In PHP there's something like `in_array`)

What solutions do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adiga's response shows a convenient way to do this if you prefer not to make any changes to your view-model. One alternative you could consider is using a computed property and moving this logic into the view-model instead. You could do this leveraging using the `computedFrom` decorator:

**app.js**

```js
import {computedFrom} from 'aurelia-framework'; 

export class App{
  car = { model : ''};

  constructor(){
    this.allModels = ['Ferrari','Ford','Renault'];
  }

  @computedFrom('car.model')
  get showCar() {
    return this.allModels.indexOf(this.car.model) > -1;
  }
}
```

Then in your view you could do something like this:

**app.html**

```
<template>
    <h2 if.bind="showCar">
        ${car.price}
    </h2>
</template>
```

That way you can clean up the view logic but also avoid dirty checking that would result from needing to watch and re-calculate the `showCar` property. Functionally the approaches are the same, though this approach may make life easier if you plan to unit test the view-model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript expressions inside `if` and `show` bindings in Aurelia. So, if you have a property called `allModels: string[]` in your class, you can simply use [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_indexof_array.asp):

```
<h2 if.bind="allModels.indexOf(car.model) > -1">
    ${car.price}
</h2>
```

If you don't have `allModels` property, you could also hardcode:

`if.bind="['Ferrari','Ford','Renault'].indexOf(car.model) > -1"`

Comment: This method only works on the initial page load, and will not update the view if the contents of the array changes.